# Нужен ли тег [minecraft]?

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки, описание-метки, переименование-метки

Признаться, когда-то игра в `Minecraft` подтолкнула меня к изучения Java *(потому что Java на слуху у всех игроков в minecraft и, когда я хотел изучать свой первый язык, то вопроса "какой язык изучать?" у меня не стояло)*. Похоже, этим же руководствуются некоторые игроки, которые приходят на сайт с [вопросами не по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1282181/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-custom-model-data).

Я ставлю под сомнение целесообразность существования метки [minecraft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) по-крайней мере в том виде, в котором она существует сейчас. На моей памяти *(а я на сайте не очень долго - около года)* было два оффтоп-вопроса с данной меткой. Описание метки стимулирует игроков задавать вопросы не по теме.

В Minecraft есть только одна вещь, непосредственно относящаяся к программированию. Это, если я не ошибаюсь, `minecraft-forge` - специальное API для разработки модов. Всё остальное *(как создать свой игровой сервер, как исправить ту или иную ошибку)* будет закрыто и заминусовано, как уже происходило не один раз.

Я предлагаю либо удалить метку [minecraft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), либо изменить её описание в сторону `minecraft-forge` *(по сути главный инструмент мододелов в minecraft)*, либо заменить существующую метку на метку [minecraft-forge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forge)

Answer (score 3):

На [Code Golf](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/) майнкрафт [считается](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7823/32091) языком программирования. И вот [пачка обсуждений](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=minecraft), в том числе [способы ввода-вывода](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7491/32091) и [подсчёт размера программы](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7600/32091).

Ну и несколько программ:

- [Вывод текущего времени](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65026/32091)
- [Сумма 5 кубов](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161518/32091)
- [Сложение двух чисел](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84588/32091)

Так что может проблема вовсе не в метке?

Comment: Да уж, не знал, что майнкрафт так спрогрессировал)) Так, а в чём тогда проблема, если не в метке? Хотите сказать, что проблемы нет? Или что? Не понял просто.

Comment: @Zhenyria, понятия не имею, я в нём не разбираюсь. Может надо какое-то описание приделать. А может просто постят как и другой оффтопик, даже если метки нет. Может кто разбирающийся придёт и расскажет)